# Isomorphism and transformation matrix in Linear maps

Tags: linear-transformations, change-of-basis, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $A =\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$. Then define  $T(A)=\begin{pmatrix} b & d \\ a & c\end{pmatrix}$  and $S(A)=\begin{pmatrix} a& d \\  c& b\end{pmatrix}$. Also $T,S \in \mathcal{L}(M_{2 \times 2}(R))$.

Define $ \pi(A) = \begin{pmatrix} tr(A)& (tr\circ T)A \\  (tr\circ S)A & (tr\circ T\circ S)A\end{pmatrix}$, $\pi \in \mathcal{L}(M_{2 \times 2}(R))$

Given the bases  matrix, $ \delta=
\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\bigg\}
$, I am interested in the matrix form of $[\pi]_\delta^\delta$
and its implication.

$\underline{Attempt:}$

I apply  $\pi$ on each of the given basis.

$\pi\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$,
$\pi\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$,
$\pi\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$,
$\pi\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Then : $[\pi]_\delta^\delta = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &0&1 \\ 1&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&1&0 \\0&1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$

I tried using $ A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\4&5\end{pmatrix}$, to check the computation.

$\pi \begin{pmatrix}2&3\\4&5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}7&7\\5&9\end{pmatrix}  $

Let $  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &0&1 \\ 1&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&1&0 \\0&1&0&1 \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}A_{2\times2} &B_{2\times2} \\ C_{2\times 2} & D_{2\times 2} \end{pmatrix} $

Then $ \pi A^T = \begin{pmatrix}A_{2\times2} &B_{2\times2} \\ C_{2\times 2} & D_{2\times 2} \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}2&3\\4&5\end{pmatrix}^T = \begin{pmatrix}7&7\\5&9\end{pmatrix}   $

Does this attempt make any sense? What is the implication of this transformation? I observe the $[\pi]_\delta^\delta$ is not invertible, will this imply the transformation is not invertible?

Thank you!

$\textbf{Edit}$

Please if you find this post not relevant, I would be so happy to learn from you why this is the case. There were first instances where I typed something different from what was in the note and I have  corrected this. I came up with the example case because I found no other numerical example online and I am willing to learn more why this works and the intuitive idea behind it. Numerical errors can be corrected but I am more interested in the why? Thank you so much !

Comment: Redo the commutation of $\pi$ on the basis, it looks like you mixed up some entry locations. Specificially the entry in the top left corner should be $5$ for the example. So there must be a mistake earlier.

Comment: @AHusain Thank you ! it was incorrectly written, but entered correctly in the bigger matrix. And the entry of A was also entered wrongly, hence why you observed 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I was looking for was rewriting A in terms of the bases:

$ A = \begin{pmatrix}2&3\\4&5\end{pmatrix}  $

as:

$ A = \begin{pmatrix}2&3\\4&5\end{pmatrix}  = 2 \begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} + 3\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix} + 4 \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix} + 5 \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} $

Now, By linearity of $\pi$, it follows that:

$ \pi(A)   = \pi \bigg(2 \begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} + 3\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix} + 4 \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix} + 5 \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \bigg) $

This is equivalent to (by linearity property):

$ \pi(A)   = 2 \cdot \pi\begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} + 3 \cdot \pi \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix} + 4 \cdot \pi\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}  + 5 \cdot \pi \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}  $

Observe that, the $\pi(\cdot)$, in the computation above are the entries of:

$$[\pi]_\delta^\delta = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &0&1 \\ 1&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&1&0 \\0&1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$.

This establishes why $\pi(A)$ and $\pi A^T $, gives the same answer.

It is then obvious then why the $[\pi]_\delta^\delta$ is the transformation matrix.